# Passing a function as an argument vs Calling it inside. Which one is recomended in Python

Tags: python

Lets say I have three functions in one module as defined below:

```
def add_nums(a, b):
    return a + b

def sum_and_square_one(add_nums, a, b):
    result = add_nums(a,b)
    return result*result

def sum_and_square_two(a, b):
   result = add_nums(a,b)
   return result*result
```

Both functions `sum_and_square_one` and `sum_and_square_two` do the same task. But the former takes `add_nums` as an argument while the latter calls `add_nums` inside. My question is which one is the better way. Passing a function as an argument or calling inside a function?

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to call the **same** function then there is no point in passing it as an argument every time. *(this is the case in your example)*

If you, however, want to **dynamically** call different (maybe similar) functions, then passing the appropiate function as an argument would make sense.

Comment: I gave the example just to try to show a demonstration. The function to be passed as an argument or to be called inside doesn't necessarily be a fixed (one) function. It can be any function.

Comment: @Zerihun Yes, I also just used your example to try to point out when you would use an argument and when not. If you're saying you want to be able to change the way one part of your function works, you can pass that part to the function as an argument (rather than writing multiple functions that only differ in a couple of lines). spectras has given a good and simple example for what I mean by this.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your use case. Do you need the function to change the way it works depending on that argument?

Or, rewriting your meaningless example into a bit less meaningless example (but still quite):

```
def add_nums(a, b):
    return a + b

def do_something_then_square(a, b, what_to_do):
    result = what_to_do(a, b)
    return result * result

def sum_then_square(a, b):
   result = add_nums(a, b)
   return result * result

# Then you do:
sum_then_square(2, 5)                                          # 49
do_something_then_square(2, 5, what_to_do=add_nums)            # 49
do_something_then_square(2, 5, what_to_do=lambda a, b: a + b)  # 49
do_something_then_square(2, 5, what_to_do=lambda a, b: a * b)  # 100
do_something_then_square(2, 5, what_to_do=min)                 # 4
do_something_then_square(2, 5, what_to_do=complex)             # (-21+20j)
```

Only question is: do you need that added flexibility? Otherwise it's just useless additional typing. That question must be answered on a case by case basis; it needs a complete example to give a useful answer.